# what kind of server do i need with my android application?

Tags: android

Actually, I want to create an android application which it will store and retrieve data from the server. The data that I will be storing and retrieving are in string and image format. There are different kind of servers, such as application server, database server and web service but I am confused which server will work better with my application.

Comment: what is the purpose of the server?

Comment: Just to store data, such as images and information's and that images and information's can be seen on different android devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Servers like that are already built. Just use [parse.com](http://www.parse.com). Its practically free and way easy to use.